# INSERÇÃO DE DADOS EM VÁRIAS TABELAS - Java 8 + Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro simples de empresa, para me ajudar no trabalho, neste caso uma empresa pode ter vários endereços, e estou tentando tratar essa particularidade... Tenho 2 tabelas no banco de dados... cadastro_empresa; cadastro_endereco;

O problema está acontecendo quando tenho 2 ou mais endereços por empresa... Ao inserir o endereço no form ele vai para uma tableview, assim consigo inserir quantos endereços eu quiser e cada endereço ocupa uma linha da tableview, quando eu vou gravar as informações no banco, faço um laço e pego os dados da tableview pra gravar no banco... Mas não consigo colocar todos os enderecos, somente o primeiro... Vou postar o código e caso alguém me ajude a ver onde estou errando, agradeço... Já instanciei o objeto endereço dentro do for pra ver se a cada iteração no laço ele criava um novo objeto com os dados de cada endereço, mas não vai tbm... Realmente não sei o que estou errando na minha lógica...

```
@FXML private void salvarRegistro(ActionEvent event) {
    modEmpresa.setIndex(Integer.parseInt(txtIndex.getText().trim()));
    modEmpresa.setRazaoSocial(txtRazaoSocial.getText().trim());
    modEmpresa.setNomeFantasia(txtNomeFantasia.getText().trim());
    modEmpresa.setFk_documento(Mascara.onlyAlfaNumericValue(txtCnpj));

    List<TabelaEndereco> cg = tblEndereco.getItems();
    ModEndereco newModEndereco;
        for (TabelaEndereco tab : cg) {
            modEndereco.setFk_documento(Mascara.onlyAlfaNumericValue(txtCnpj));
            modTipoEndereco.setIndexador(tab.getCodigoTipoEndereco());
            modEndereco.setFk_tipo_endereco(modTipoEndereco);
            modLogradouro.setIndexador(tab.getCodigoLogradouro());
            modEndereco.setFk_logradouro(modLogradouro);
            modEndereco.setEndereco(tab.getEndereco());
            modEndereco.setNumero(tab.getNumero());
            modEndereco.setComplemento(tab.getComplemento());
            modEndereco.setBairro(tab.getBairro());
            modEndereco.setCodigoPostal(tab.getCep());
            modPais.setIndexador(tab.getCodigoPais());
            modEndereco.setFk_pais(modPais);
            modEstado.setIndexador(tab.getCodigoEstado());
            modEndereco.setFk_estado(modEstado);
            modCidade.setIndexador(tab.getCodigoCidade());
            modEndereco.setFk_cidade(modCidade); 
        }

    mod.setCadEmpresa(modEmpresa);
    mod.setEndereco(modEndereco);
    dao.inserirRegistro(mod);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vamos lá**

vou fazer um exemplo rápido aqui para você entender onde está errando e tentar resolver seu problema.

Código da classe empresa

```
public class Empesa {
private String nomeFantasia;
private String razaoSocial;
private List<Endereco> enderecos;

public Empesa() {
    super();
}

public Empesa(String nomeFantasia, String razaoSocial, List<Endereco> enderecos) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
    this.razaoSocial = razaoSocial;
    this.enderecos = enderecos;
}

public String getNomeFantasia() {
    return nomeFantasia;
}

public void setNomeFantasia(String nomeFantasia) {
    this.nomeFantasia = nomeFantasia;
}

public String getRazaoSocial() {
    return razaoSocial;
}

public void setRazaoSocial(String razaoSocial) {
    this.razaoSocial = razaoSocial;
}

public List<Endereco> getEnderecos() {
    return enderecos;
}

public void setEnderecos(List<Endereco> enderecos) {
    this.enderecos = enderecos;
}
```

}

Código da classe Endereco

```
public class Endereco {
private String logradouro;
private String numero;
private String complemento;
private String bairro;

public Endereco(String logradouro, String numero, String complemento, String bairro) {
    this.logradouro = logradouro;
    this.numero = numero;
    this.complemento = complemento;
    this.bairro = bairro;
}

public String getLogradouro() {
    return logradouro;
}

public void setLogradouro(String logradouro) {
    this.logradouro = logradouro;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    numero = numero;
}

public String getComplemento() {
    return complemento;
}

public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
    complemento = complemento;
}

public String getBairro() {
    return bairro;
}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {
    bairro = bairro;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nlogradouro: " + logradouro + ", numero: " + numero + ", complemento: " + complemento
            + ", bairro: " + bairro + " \n";
}
```

}

Agora o teste pra você entender como fazer ai no seu código

```
public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // Criando a empresa
    Empesa empresa1 = new Empesa("Empresa teste", "Razao Social teste", null); // observe que passei null no endereço, pois ainda não temos endereço cadastrado 
    
    // Criando os endereços
    Endereco endereco1 = new Endereco("Rua 1 ", "1A", "Casa 01", "Bairro 01");
    Endereco endereco2 = new Endereco("Rua 2 ", "2A", "Casa 02", "Bairro 02");
    Endereco endereco3 = new Endereco("Rua 3 ", "3A", "Casa 03", "Bairro 03");
    
    // Vamos fazer de conta que aqui é sua tableview cadastrando os endereços
    List<Endereco> listaEnderecosTableview = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    listaEnderecosTableview.add(endereco1);
    listaEnderecosTableview.add(endereco2);
    listaEnderecosTableview.add(endereco3);
    
    List<Endereco> listaDeEnderecos = new ArrayList<Endereco>();
    
    // aqui você vai iterar a lista de endereços criado lá no Tableview
    for (Endereco endereco : listaEnderecosTableview) {
        listaDeEnderecos.add(endereco); // aqui você tá adicionando cada endereço da Tableview a uma lista (listaDeEnderecos) que criamos fora do for
        empresa1.setEnderecos(listaDeEnderecos);// aqui você seta a lista de endereços na empresa correspondente ao cadastro
    }
    
    // Simpes impressão para você ver que tem 3 endereços
    System.out.println("Nome: " + empresa1.getNomeFantasia() + " \nLista de Endereços:  \n" + empresa1.getEnderecos().toString());

}
```

}

[print do teste/console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY6Zh.png)